# UWP - Pass event to control (tunneling)

Tags: c#, wpf, events, uwp

I have a UWP question about inheriting/ passing a event to a user control from the parent view to child.

I created a user control to display text overlays (see code below). We had a parent view that would display an overlay when the window is resized (see code below). The overlay would display the dimensions of the window when this even is triggered.

I moved the overlay to a user control and now I'm trying to pass that resized event to the overlay control. The hope is that we can register more events to the overlay control so it can display more then the resize
information. However, I'm not sure the best way to do this. My first idea was inheriting from the view, so i could just listen to the event from the overlay control, but that resulted in errors.
I believe due to the fact that the parent view has a ViewModel (i also created one for the overlay, not sure if its actually needed yet).
I have been reading about a lot of possible ways to do this, but I'm not sure which would be the best way to do this. Does anyone have any insight on this issue ? I would be open to suggestions, links, or just a general answer of
what is the best way to achieve this in our project.

Parent view

[image]

User Control

[image]

Parent Event 
[image]

Control class

[image]

Some information i have been reading about:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/17449/MVVM-Framework/ViewModels/ViewModel-relationships-ISupportParentViewModel

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/preview-events

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/742077f6-e875-44d1-8bc4-6e6516db9eda/passing-the-parent-control-event-to-child-controls?forum=winforms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview

http://irisclasson.com/2013/12/10/passing-event-arguments-from-xaml-in-windows-store-apps-inputconverter-inputconverterparameter-etc/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

**Update**
Adding the viewModel to the parent viewModel (terminal), and passing it to the control via the Datacontext did not work

Comment: Could you share a mini sample, because your code screenshot is hard to read. it is not good for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misusing the bindings. x:Bind and Binding are using different types of context. For this binding to work we would need to set the parent's element Datacontext to 'this'. x:Bind on the other hand does this implicitly.

```
<views:OverlayView DataContext="{x:Bind ViewModel.Overlay}"></views:OverlayView>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you're already using MVVM, I'd recommend going the full route utilizing "Interactivity", "Commands", and "child ViewModels". This is a commonly used patter in MVVM WPF applications, and can be applied to UWP apps as well.

## Using "Interactivity" and interactions

The interactivity / behaviors library from Microsoft allows you to bind events in XAML to an `ICommand` in the `ViewModel`. You can get the managed NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/).

From the official [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/master/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample/InvokeCommandControl.xaml), shortened:

```xml
<Button x:Name="button1" Content="Increment">
  <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=button1}">
      <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateCountCommand}"/>
    </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
  </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

## Forward command data to child ViewModel

Having this event now routed to your command in your parent ViewModel, you can now either call your overlay ViewModel and pass the info directly to it:

```cs
private readony IOverlayViewModel _overlayViewModel;

public ICommand UpdateCountCommand { get; set; }

ctor(IOverlayViewModel overlayViewModel)
{
    _overlayViewModel = overlayViewModel;
    UpdatedCountCommand = new MyICommandImplementation(UpdatedCountCommand_Executed);
}

private void UpdatedCountCommand_Executed(/* Add correct method signature */)
{
    // If needed, retrieve data from parameter...

    // Update overlay ViewModel text
    _overlayViewModel.Text = ""; // Whichever text was calculated before
}
```

Or you use a messenger ([mediator pattern](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns/mediator-design-pattern-c-sharp)) to send it to an overlay.

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I read about mediator. It looks like it hides dependencies. I really like the behaviors! I'm confused on where the Interactivity element would go in my case. Do i put it under my Overlay control in the parent or am i confused?  

Ex: => <parent><control><interactivity resizeEvent></control></parent>

Comment: NVM, its event hanlder, not an event.

Comment: @AJ_ Yeah, the mediator hides dependencies even more, by not referencing the child ViewModel, in this example. Both versions have benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: Yeah, i have been trying to use a shared reference to the view model, that both parent and child have, a event delegate (maybe its a command), or Interactivity. Have yet to get any of those to work, but ill keep you updated.

Comment: Got it to work by usine x:bind instead of binding. Its now binding to the DataContext. Thanks for the help !!!